# Who can carry out airworthiness inspections?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, caa-uk-regulations, airworthiness

My understanding is that aircraft regularly have inspections for defects just like cars in the U.K. have an [annual MOT test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOT_test) to check their condition and safety.

My question is, who can do these inspections and what qualifications/certifications do they need?

I'm primarily interested in CAA requirements but FAA requirements would also be interesting to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can speak to the FAA requirements.  The basic requirement for the annual inspection (commercial aircraft have additional requirements) comes from [14 CFR Part 91.409](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dd05b659e1167b0e23cea65046434719&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1409&rgn=div8)

> §91.409   Inspections.
>
> (a) Except as provided in paragraph (c) of this section, no person may
>   operate an aircraft unless, within the preceding 12 calendar months,
>   it has had—
>
> (1) An annual inspection in accordance with part 43 of this chapter
>   and has been approved for return to service by a person authorized by
>   §43.7 of this chapter; or...

And the related requirement regarding who can perform this is covered in Part 43 and is in two parts; who can perform the work and who can approve the return to service.

The work must be performed by someone specified in [14 CFR Part 43.3](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e44cf0cec072421d4937e65245f2d721&mc=true&node=se14.1.43_13&rgn=div8) in which the general case is:

> §43.3   Persons authorized to perform maintenance, preventive
>   maintenance, rebuilding, and alterations.
>
> (a) Except as provided in this section and §43.17, no person may
>   maintain, rebuild, alter, or perform preventive maintenance on an
>   aircraft, airframe, aircraft engine, propeller, appliance, or
>   component part to which this part applies. Those items, the
>   performance of which is a major alteration, a major repair, or
>   preventive maintenance, are listed in appendix A.
>
> (b) The holder of a mechanic certificate may perform maintenance,
>   preventive maintenance, and alterations as provided in Part 65 of this
>   chapter.
>
> (c) The holder of a repairman certificate may perform maintenance,
>   preventive maintenance, and alterations as provided in part 65 of this
>   chapter.

And the approval for return to service must be per [14 CFR Part 43.7](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e44cf0cec072421d4937e65245f2d721&mc=true&node=se14.1.43_17&rgn=div8)

> §43.7   Persons authorized to approve aircraft, airframes, aircraft
>   engines, propellers, appliances, or component parts for return to
>   service after maintenance, preventive maintenance, rebuilding, or
>   alteration.
>
> (a) Except as provided in this section and §43.17, no person, other
>   than the Administrator, may approve an aircraft, airframe, aircraft
>   engine, propeller, appliance, or component part for return to service
>   after it has undergone maintenance, preventive maintenance,
>   rebuilding, or alteration.
>
> (b) The holder of a mechanic certificate or an inspection
>   authorization may approve an aircraft, airframe, aircraft engine,
>   propeller, appliance, or component part for return to service as
>   provided in Part 65 of this chapter.

Requirements for mechanics and inspection authorizations are spelled out in [14 CFR Part 65, Subpart D](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e02e1787523a68634890b1fc57049315&mc=true&node=sp14.2.65.d&rgn=div6).

The regulations also allow manufacturers and repair stations among a limited number of others to perform the work as well.  (see links)

Comment: "The holder of a mechanic certificate" seems vague. What certificate is that? Is there an FAA mechanic scheme?

Comment: @Notts90 It means a licensed A&P (Airframe and Powerplant). Mechanics who work on aircraft must go through a lengthly certification process, but that doesn't mean that the person performing your inspection is a *licensed* A&P, they just have to be working under the supervision of a licensed A&P. It takes 2000 hours of experience to get the A&P license from the FAA.

Comment: @RonBeyer so any competent person under the supervision of a licensed A&P mechanic can perform the inspection? Is there a specific name for the license?

Comment: In the FAA world, this is a [Mechanics Certificate](https://www.faa.gov/mechanics/records/) but are more commonly called A&P's. Yes, any "competent" person can perform the work, however it has to be signed off by a certificated A&P in the log book so it would behoove the A&P signing off to verify the work, ultimately their certificate is the one on the line.

Comment: @RonBeyer that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you! If you post it I'll accept.

Comment: @RonBeyer looking at another page from the link you posted I found [this FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/mechanics/become/faq/) on mechanics and who can do the role etc. answers my questions for the FAA side entirely.